# Making iOS or Android apps that makes REST API calls to Django, and setting up backend servers

Tags: django, api, nginx, mobile, server

My friends and I want to build an app iOS and Android that makes REST API calls to Django, and Im in charge of setting up the backend server. I've heard a lot of things like about nginx and stuff, but I can't find anywhere how to start things off and make a useable server and such.

Ive heard good things about Digital Ocean, but I dont know where to start off.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new service, I would advise a look at [Django-Rest-Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for building API service. Then again if it's just for an API why not use [Flask-Restles](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)s it so much simpler.

And you do want to put web server / reverse proxy in front these. NGINX is pretty good Apache works as well, or Gunigorn. For as small app these can run on the same server regardless if you use digital ocean or something else.

However, it sounds like you have a lot of new concepts here. Maybe just use something like [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) and you are up much faster if you just need IOS backend.